# Возвратить предупреждение из jar

Tags: java, jar

Имеется jar для вызова, необходимо возвращать из него значение предупрежедние.Как можно получить оттуда такой ответ. 
К примеру, мой код заканчивается

```
...
int ex=parse(file_to_go);

if(ex==-1){ System.out.print("Error!"); System.exit(-1);}
if(ex==1){ System.out.print("Error in DB!"); System.exit(1);}
```

Т.е в любом случае после вызова jar придет ответ, что вызов был успешный. Как можно вызвать его и чтобы пришло предупреждение, что что-то в нем выполнилось некорректно?

Comment: В Java следует выбрасывать исключение, если что-то _выполнилось некорректно_. Проверка возвращаемых значений и коды ошибок - это решения из мира C.

Comment: Можно ли подключить jar к проекту?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev  у меня есть обработка ошибок. т.е. в методе parse есть отлов ошибок. Можно ли сделать, к примеру, чтобы если из метода вызов был с ошибкой, то он как-то олавливался в методе main. То что указано выше- код из метода main

Comment: @RomanC он подключен  к проекту

Comment: Приведённый вами код уже делает то, что вам нужно - устанавливает переменную `%errorlevel%` в консоли Windows и переменную `$?` в nix-консолях в соответствии с числом переданным в `System.exit()`. Но как я уже писал, коды возврата из методов и использование `System.exit()` - это плохая практика в Java.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev как можно посмотреть содержимое этой переменной?

Comment: В cmd - `echo %errorlevel%`, в sh - `echo $?`. Но это уже вопрос относящийся не к Java, а консольным оболочкам.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Спасибо за помощь!)